# How can I fix the problem with my discord bot that doesn't want to react to messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to test some new things so I wanted to create a bot discord so I started to do something very basic  :

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()

DISCORD_TOKEN = "my token"

#when the bot is online
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is online")


#the bot reacts to messages
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)


client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

and when I run the code the bot goes online but the bot doesn't react to the message nothing happens so sure the code is basic for now but the bot was supposed to react to the message in the terminal right?

this is the first time I use the discord.py library... so Can someone help me to solve this problem please I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is that you haven't enabled the `message_content` intent - you need to set that to be able to read message content.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # explicitly enable the message content intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

You will also need to enable this intent for your bot/application in the Discord Developer portal.

- The `message_content` intent is on the [first page of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).
- [Discord intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).